# require 'bundler' error, cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Unable to run `rails console`, `rails -v` etc. Already tried all of the solutions, reinstalled ruby, installed bundler but neither worked for me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    3: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    2: from /var/www/App/releases/XXXXXXXXXXX/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
```

Comment: What you do get when you run `gem show bundler`? Also, have you tried running `bundle exec rails X`?

Comment: @avlazarov Similar error with different paths and message.

Comment: @avlazarov gem show bundler => ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command show

Comment: Pardon, it should be `gem info bundler`.

Comment: Same error as above however `bundler -v` returns `Bundler version 1.16.1`

Comment: It's hard to guess, without a debugging session. What I'd try is to do `gem env`, and `which bundler` for hints about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A few days back I also land up into the same issue, I think it was due to spring caching some gems and configurations. I fixed it by running `bundle pristine`.

This restores installed gems based on the `Gemfile.lock` to pristine condition from files located in the gem cache.